# Organizing lines of a file using C

Tags: c

I have multiple huge text files:

`cat file.txt`

```
# strings from 2019

aaaaaaacacsadsaludshafnvhlav
adskhfgdasknad
adkskfgsahfnasdkfdsaf

#strings from 2018

c++:"cacsadsalu
adsk()&hfgdasksa
adkskfgsahfnadkfdsaf
```

I would like to remove all the '\n' from the lines that do not start with '#' and then reorder my file so that I write only 10 characters per each line. I think the best option is to create a buffer of size 11 with `buf[10]='\n'`, and write the output of fgets into `buf[0]` to `buf[9]`. But am not sure how to append the next lines into that buffer properly.

`cat result.txt`

```
# strings from 2019
aaaaaaacac
sadsaludsh
afnvhlavad
skhfgdaskn
adadkskfgs
ahfnasdkfd
saf
#strings from 2018
c++:"cacsa
dsaluadsk(
)&hfgdasks
aadkskfgsa
hfnadkfdsa
f
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        FILE *pinput;
        FILE *poutput;
        pinput  = fopen("file.txt","r");
        poutput = fopen("result.txt","w");
        char fileText[1000];

        //will add errno for fopen()

        char *buf[11];
        buf[10] = '\n';

        while(fgets(fileText,1000,pinput) != NULL){
                //remove the new line
                if (fileText[0] != '#'){
                        int len = strlen(fileText);
                        fileText[len - 1] = '\0';
                }
        }

        fclose(pinput);
        fclose(poutput)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: you need the input file and another output file... reading and writing to the same file is bound to create problems (eg: do you read what you just wrote?, to you overwrite something you are about to read?)

Comment: I'll edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You are absolutely sure no line has more than 998 characters (999th being the `'\n'` and 1000th being the `'\0'`)? If you have longer lines, your statement `fileText[len - 1] = '\0';` will overwrite some important data.

Comment: I'll definitely have to ensure the line size is properly set.

Comment: You can keep a pointer to the buffer (I'll call it `p`) and print 10 characters starting from there: `fprintf(poutput, "%.*s", 10, p); p+=10;` in a loop. Make sure you keep the last few characters for the next line but move them to the beginning of `textFile`: `memmove(textFile, p, 10); p = textFile;`

Comment: fgets(...., 1000) ensures that you will read at most 999 chars from the file and the last entry in the buffer will be set to '\0'. For robustness purposes, suppose that you may have lines longer than 999 chars and so, the buffer may not contain a terminating '\n'. So, add a check before overwriting the last char: if (fileText[len - 1] == '\n') fileText[len - 1] = '\0';

Comment: When you already have some data in `textFile` and need to `fgets()` more, read into the existing `'\0'` effectively "enlarging" the string: `fgets(textFile + strlen(textFile), 1000 - strlen(textFile), pinput);`... also (for performance sake) try to avoid unnecessary calls to `strlen()` and instead keep the lengths in variables

Comment: Nice project! I like it... seems like you're having fun! Don't want to spoil your fun with a ready-made code :)

Comment: lol yeah! It's definitely interesting! It's for genomics where the chromosomes (strings) could be billions of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it by splitting your file reading logic into two blocks:

1. Heading : Write line as it is to output file
2. Body: maintain a count of characters written and write each character one by one, printing an additional `\n` whenever number of characters written reaches multiple of ten

Here is sample code:

```c
// Maintains number of Characters written for a heading        
int nHeadingCharsWritten = 0;
while(fgets(fileText,1000,pInput) != NULL) {
    if (strlen(fileText) > 1) { // Ignore empty lines
        if (fileText[0] == '#') { // Case for Heading 
            fputc('\n', pOutput);
            fputs(fileText, pOutput);
            nHeadingCharsWritten = 0; // reset number of characters for new heading
        } else { // Case for Body
            int nLen = strlen(fileText);
            for (int i = 0; i < nLen - 1; i++) {
                // Go to new line if number of characters written reach multiple of ten
                if (nHeadingCharsWritten > 0 && nHeadingCharsWritten % 10 == 0) {
                    fputc('\n', pOutput);
                }
                // write other characters as usual
                fputc(fileText[i], pOutput);
                nHeadingCharsWritten++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this, I was able to see expected output:

```
src : $ cat result.txt 

# strings from 2019
aaaaaaacac
sadsaludsh
afnvhlavad
skhfgdaskn
adadkskfgs
ahfnasdkfd
saf
#strings from 2018
c++:"cacsa
dsaluadsk(
)&hfgdasks
aadkskfgsa
hfnadkfdsa
f
```

Comment: `fprintf(pOutput, fileText);` if `fileText` contains `'%'` you'll get garbled output ==> `fprintf(pOutput, "%s", fileText);` or `fputs(fileText, pOutput);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for point this out. Let me update my answer.